# nonce value response delay cause send data without nonce value

Tags: c#, braintree, nonce

In my checkout form I have to use some jQuery validation plugin to validate complex validation process, at the end of the track I send form data like this

```html
 $.validate({
        modules: 'security , date',
        onSuccess: function () {
          
               // do Ajax call
            return false;
        },
    });
```

but also I use Braintree setup like this

```html
 braintree.setup($("#btCilentToken").val(), 'dropin', {
        container: 'dropin', paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {

           //get nonce save to javascript variable that be used in my final ajax call           
        }
    });
```

now the problem is

sending form data-> tokenizing begins -> sending form data ends ->
(somewhere here the nonce value response back to server)
-> tokenizing ends

so I missed the nonce value because of delay

I tried differed object , timeout and some other approach but the problem is the function inside another object prevent me to sort them in proper order

every practice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new BT libs solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Braintree.js hijacks the form submit event, so you should be able to call `$.validate` from within the `paymentMethodNonceReceived` callback and the form will never be submitted. I would imagine your integration would end up looking something like this:

```
braintree.setup($("#btClientToken").val(), 'dropin', {
  container: 'dropin',
  paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
    $.validate({
      modules: 'security , date',
      onSuccess: function () {
        // do Ajax call and use nonce
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it is not working because I need $.validation in the context to validate everything otherwise onSuccess not act properly since it need to be fired onsubmit :(

Comment: There are quite a few ways to ensure your `onSuccess` method will execute in the appropriate context. Since you are using jQuery, you can use `$.proxy` to ensure that context. [Here is an example using the previous code](https://gist.github.com/kyledetella/1b3c3d935db6e728afd0).

It is also worth noting that the `paymentMethodNonceReceived` callback happens as a result of `onsubmit`, so that is a good place to run your validations.